# How to list cookies in Play

Tags: java, cookies, playframework-2.1

Using PlayFramework (in Java), I'd like to log the list of all cookies name Play can read.

I tried to call `request().cookies()` but it's not a List, it's an object, and there is no List in this object.

I can call `request().cookie(String name);` but this expect that I know the cookie's name, which I don't.

How can I do then ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution I just made, I don't know if it's the best, but it works :

```
for (String cookieStr : request.headers().get("Cookie")) {
    String name = cookieStr.substring(0, cookieStr.indexOf("="));

    Logger.info("Name of the cookie : " + name);

    Cookie cookie = request.cookie(name); // Get the instance of the cookie !
}
```